# Laravel - how to save multiple rows

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, request, store

I have this store method:

```
    public function store(Requests\OfferRequest $request)
        {
    $start = $request->input('from'); // 04/24/2016 12:00 AM
    $end = $request->input('to); // 07/24/2016 12:00 AM

                $auction = new Auction($request->all());
                Auth::user()->auctions()->save($auction);
//how to get saved auction ID ?
    }
```

Now I need to save empty records for each day from $start to $end in Offer table ... only I need to put id of saved auction at auction_id in offers table...

Can I save this in one query or I need to use for loop ? What is the best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way instead:

```
//how to get saved auction ID ?
$auction = new Auction();
$auction->fill($request->all());
$auction->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
$auction->save();
$auction_id = $auction->id;

$dStart = new DateTime($start);
$dEnd   = new DateTime($to);

// Will loop through everyday from $dStart to $dEnd
while ($dStart < $dEnd) {        
    // current date of the loop formated for db use
    $date = $dStart->format('Y-m-d');

    // Code to insert date to Offer 


    $dStart->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
}
```

Comment: where is AUTH? also how to make loop to save rows for each day between $start and $end

Comment: Im writing the code for writing multiple rows gimme a min, about \Auth: is it user_id that reference the user with the auction?

Comment: Added the user_id to auction from the current logged user with \Auth::user() just as you have it, with respect the loop are you going to insert 91 rows? respectively with the dates?